# Unknown character set index for field received from server

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have an instance of MySQL 5.0.4.1 with an application written in Hibernate. On one of the pages, I get the following error message in the server log:

> Unknown character set index for field '123' received from server.
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getCharsetNameForIndex(Connection.java:1664)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.(Field.java:144)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.unpackField(MysqlIO.java:506)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:280)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1319)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1218)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2233)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2193)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2174)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:536)
> at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:268)
> at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:293)
> at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:194)
> at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:186)
> at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:162)
> at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:603)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:579)
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:556)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.doCloseTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:284)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:100)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)
> at org.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)
> at org.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:170)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:176)
> at $Proxy6.getDataFromDatabase(Unknown Source)
> at org.myCompany.myAction.load(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
> at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:274)
> at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:194)
> at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
> at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
> at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
> at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:787)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:908)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:247)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
> at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
> at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
> at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
> at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
> at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:217)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
> at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:229)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
> at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:213)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:280)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:509)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:509)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:209)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:509)
> at com.iplanet.ias.web.connector.nsapi.NSAPIProcessor.process(NSAPIProcessor.java:157)
> at com.iplanet.ias.web.WebContainer.service(WebContainer.java:579)

This error occurs on a production environment so I don't know which query produced the problem, but I do know that none of my tables has a column named '123'. Do you have any suggestions about what might be causing this problem?

**Edit:** As a followup, I found that this behavior is a [known bug in MySQL 5.0.4](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23645), but I haven't found a good wokaround since I don't have the option of upgrading mySQL.

Comment: You cannot upgrade MySQL, but can you downgrage it? The bug reports indicates that using 5.0.3 instead of 5.0.4 should avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that somehow the character set for the field has been set to an invalid value, run this SQL on the server with the problem replacing the table name and the column 'Collation' will show the characterset for each varchar/char fields

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN table_name;
```

You can then change the character set of a field by using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally, MySQL is mapping out the indexes across the columns. Normally this is done using integers that represent the column index. Most indexes are actually a compound index once built (col 1 + col 3) which form something like `field 13`.

Likely this happened when migrating data from dev into production when the stack is not an exact replica.

As [3urdoch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292662/3urdoch) mentioned you can pull the charset using internal MySQL function; and then change the table's charset to a compatible encoding.

Alternatively (where I'm willing to bet this issue came from) you can check if the loaded driver for the `Production` matches the loaded driver for the `Other` server. **This will prevent re-occurring issue if the `Development`/`Other` server is still being used for testing, and migrated into `Production`.**